# Can Start-Process be used in Azure Automation?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

When I try to start a process using `Start-Process` on Azure Automation, it doesn't run and remains `Idle`. Is it possible to run processes on Azure Automation?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to run Azure Automation jobs - in Azure workers and in Hybrid workers on your premises. I suppose you are trying to run a job on a Hybrid worker, so you should be able to start a process on the machine. There are some security restrictions on the processes with GUI, so you will not be able to see GUI for your process, but for the process per-se - it will be created, I just tried it myself:
[start-process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWCVM.png)

- To get more information on running jobs in Azure, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-starting-a-runbook/
- Detailed article about running jobs on Hybrid Workers is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker/

Comment: Asking for more information should really be performed in comments, you will be able to comment once you reach 50 rep.  Moreover, it is unlikely that such an old question would be of relevance to the user.  Instead you could make a great answer be describing in detail both methods of running automation jobs in azure, that way it will be useful for people that find this question by searching.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to stackoverflow and as a representatinve of Azure Automation team, my intent is to help people dealing with pressing issues. This stackoverflow is perceived by some users as a channel to report issues with Services, I believe it is fair to engage with the users here. With no reputation in this community I am challenged to give adequate help to people when more details on the issue required. Thank you for understanding.